# Creating a Stored Procedure despite errors (to transfer to different server)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I've got a database that is replicated on two servers, a live server and a test server, so that whenever it's needed the 'test' database gets overwritten by the 'live' database (so that I can reset everything if I've made a mess.)
I want an Stored Procedure in the 'test' database, that will only run in the 'test' database, but to do this I need to have it in the 'live' database as well, so that it can be copied over when 'test' is overwritten.
 The procedure starts:

```
if @@SERVERNAME<>'TEST'
begin
    raiserror ('NOT ON TEST! This SP must only be run on TEST.',16,1)
    return 
end
```

So that if it runs in live, it immediately exits.

Unfortunately the "Live" database server uses an older version of SQL, and doesn't seem to understand the lead/lag/over statements in the script, and refuses to create the procedure because of these "Incorrect syntax" errors.

The SP definitely works in the test server.
Is there a way to disregard the error messages when creating a stored procedure?

I've found a prior question that explained how to make *a* stored procedure with the same name, but I need the stored procedure to contain the script that the server thinks is incorrect.

Comment: Which DB are you asking about, MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: SQL Server (Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio)

Comment: Wrap the queries that don't work into a string and [execute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) them as dynamic SQL.

Comment: Thanks guys, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to not get the stored-procedure validated when created, is to run a dynamic-sql query within.

Example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.YourStoredProcedure AS 
BEGIN 

IF @@SERVERNAME<>'TEST'
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('NOT ON TEST! This SP must only be run on TEST.',16,1)
    RETURN
END

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR = N'
SELECT rowOne
, rowTwo
, valueOne
, LEAD(valueOne) OVER (PARTITION BY rowOne ORDER BY rowTwo DESC) AS preValue
FROM dbo.YourTable
'

EXEC(@SQL)

END
```

Notes:

- On the long term, try to find a better strategy than DB replication for different systems. Check Continuous Deployment
- Make sure to check concatenated dynamic-sql for potential issues (sql injection). Check [QUOTENAME()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx)